# How to prevent automake from overwriting INSTALL?

Tags: gnu, automake, autoreconf, autotools

I'm working on a project that has a custom `INSTALL` file. Running `automake --add-missing` (or more precisely, `autoreconf -i`) will generate the GNU default `INSTALL` file, and overwrite our file with it.

How can I prevent this behavior? I want it to either not generate the GNU `INSTALL` file at all, or alternatively, create it with a different name.

Also, I don't want to disable any other files that `automake` might generate.

---

**Edit 1:** From the [`automake` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Gnits.html):

> If the `--add-missing` option is given, `automake` will add a generic
>   version of the `INSTALL` file as well as the `COPYING` file containing the
>   text of the current version of the GNU General Public License […]. However, an existing `COPYING`
>   file will never be overwritten by `automake`.

It says that an existing `COPYING` file will not be overwritten, but doesn't say anything about the `INSTALL` file, so it seems like it will be unconditionally overwritten.

**Edit 2:** As requested, here are my `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am`, and also `autogen.sh` that we run to `autoreconf` the project:

`configure.ac`:

```
AC_INIT([program name], [version number], [bug report], [short name], [url])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([Main/Source/main.cpp])

AM_PROG_AS 
AC_CANONICAL_TARGET
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_PROG_CC
AC_PROG_CXX

CFLAGS="$CFLAGS $SDL_CFLAGS "
LIBS="$LIBS $SDL_LIBS"
CPPFLAGS="$SDL_CFLAGS -DLINUX
          -DLOCAL_STATE_DIR=\\\"$sharedstatedir/<program name>\\\"
          -DDATADIR=\\\"$datadir\\\" -DUSE_SDL -DGCC"

AC_PROG_INSTALL
AC_PROG_RANLIB
AC_CONFIG_FILES(<list of Makefiles in subdirs>)
AC_OUTPUT
```

`Makefile.am`:

```
SUBDIRS = FooLib Main Bar Baz
EXTRA_DIST = LICENSING <and a bunch of unrelated files>
```

`autogen.sh`:

```
autoreconf -f -i
```

Comment: Can you provide copies of your `configure.ac` and `Makefile.in`, please? Edit your question to include them, do not add them in a comment or a separate paste. Also add any other custom scripts you might be using. See https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Gnits.html#Gnits . You've probably have `--add-missing` somewhere. If you take that out, the INSTALL and COPYING files won't be created. Personally I don't think that is an especially useful option.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Thanks. Added the snippets. Removing `-i` from `autoreconf` prevents it from installing all those files.

Comment: I rather think you want that `-i` for other things, but you can confirm that yourself.

Comment: @FaheemMitha You're right, actually running it without `-i` gives an error: `required file './compile' not found`: `'automake --add-missing' can install 'compile'` I guess that's why I was using it in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of the problem was the `-f` i.e. `--force` tag to `autoreconf`.

The man page for it states: "consider all files obsolete" which is a bit vague, so I couldn't initially connect it to my problem. [Its html manual entry](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.68/html_node/autoreconf-Invocation.html) is even more misleading:

> Remake even `configure` scripts and configuration headers that are newer than their input files (`configure.ac` and, if present, `aclocal.m4`).

It only talks about configure scripts, but in reality it also handles the standard GNU files.

[And as it turns out](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=autoconf.git;a=blob;f=bin/autoreconf.in;h=9f353b09c3d161df65e219084451b1264eea4747;hb=HEAD#l210), `autoreconf -f` actually calls `automake --force-missing`, which has a more explicit description: "force update of standard files", and [its html manual entry](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/automake-Invocation.html) makes it even clearer:

> When used with `--add-missing`, causes standard files to be reinstalled even if they already exist in the source tree. […]

Removing the `-f` tag from the `autoreconf` invocation solved this.

**Conclusion:** The people working on `autoreconf` can't write manual entries. The people working on `automake` can.

Comment: Good detective work. File a documentation bug, maybe? I'm actually using `autoreconf` with the `-f` flag. Does this option have no legitimate use then? I think forcing a remake of generatef files might be an insurance policy of sorts, in case timestamps are wrong. Because of network file systems or whatever. Oh, and if you filed a bug report, link to it, either in your question or your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Add the `foreign` option to `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` in
`configure.ac`. This will tell autotools that you are not following GNU coding standards, and Automake will not create the usual GNU project text files, including the AUTHORS, COPYING, INSTALL, NEWS, README, and ChangeLog files. The automatic creation of these files is really fairly useless. You can always create them yourself.

Comment: I actually tried using `foreign` which didn't overwrite the INSTALL file, but I'd want to keep the project `gnu` compliant because that's what it has been so far. Although if that doesn't work out I guess I'll just make it `foreign`. Or is using a custom INSTALL file non-GNU already?

Comment: @zenith I looked for a way to stop the INSTALL file being rewritten, though it really should not overwrite by default - that is wacky behavior.  But I did not find anything. You could ask about this on the automake mailing list, and possibly submit a bug.  You can make your project GNU compliant just by having those files. I don't think you need to have them automatically created for you. #autotools on freenode is another place where you can sometimes find people who can answer questions. I just posted a query there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into those. And you're probably right in that having the GNU files automatically created isn't particularly useful, so I'll probably go with `foreign` if no better solutions show up.

Comment: @zenith So, I was talking to people on #autotools, and at least one person (Berndj) thinks the INSTALL overwrite thing is a bug. So, I recommend you file a bug report. If they don't agree, they will ignore it or close it or whatever. Check that the issue hasn't already been filed, of course.

Comment: BTW, if you want to talk to me, I'm usually in the U&L main chat room. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux You can ping me there.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! I just filed a bug report about it. But just after that I realized that it was the `-f` option to `autoreconf` that was causing this. It seems to forward that option as [`--force-missing`](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/automake-Invocation.html) to `automake`, which "causes standard files to be reinstalled even if they already exist". In the `autoreconf` man page it simply says "`-f` consider all files obsolete", which is not very clear about what it ends up doing.